# Required XML attribute 'adSize' was missing

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, admob

So for some reason when I place in an adview it doesn't auto fill the ads:adSize and ads:adUnitId and I am not able to select them, and my ad is displaying text that reads Required XML attribute 'adSize' was missing. also I don't think I can fill out xmlns:ads in my layout, although I may be mistaken. Why is this?

my gradles

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

second build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.matig.adtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.matig.adtest.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/adView3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I followed firebases tutorial step by step So i'm really confused as to what I'm doing wrong

Comment: i'm a different person with a different problem

Answer (score 6):

Comparison of your layout with the [sample provided in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#place_an_adview_in_your_main_activity_layout) suggests you need to add:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

and

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
```